# DataGridComboBoxCell - Can't Fill Values Programmatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm filling a DataGridView with 2 columns, a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` for a name label, and a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to act as a dropdown for selecting an SQL Column name to map to the name.

I'm going for a loop through my names, and creating a row for each of them. Each row should display the name of a field (`String` object), and in the other column should be a combo box (values are within a `List (Of String)`). I keep getting an exception raised that says 'the value is not valid':

```
For Each sourceColumn As String In sourceColumnList
    Dim item As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    Dim destcombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    item.Value = sourceColumn
    destcombo.Items.AddRange(sqlColumnSelectionList.ToArray())

    '    ERROR IS HERE, REFERRING TO INVALID COMBO BOX |
    '                                                 \|/
    list_Destination_SQLMap.Rows.Add(sourceColumn, destcombo)
Next
```

I've googled around but can only find examples of how to fix this problem with data sources that are bound, not unbound. I know I'm missing something, this is the first time I've used a `DataGridView`.

Comment: Can you include how you are adding the columns to the DataGridView as well, please?

Comment: I sure would! But i'm not programmatically adding the columns. They will always remain constant (first column containing a source field name, and the 2nd column containing a dropdown including the list of columns in the destination SQL table) so I added them via. the form designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` you also need to set its `DataSource` property to a valid source. A `DataTable` if you get the data from a database or `List (Of T)` - Your `List (Of String)` will work just fine.

Add the code below AFTER you have created and populated the `sqlColumnSelectionList`. (Don't forget to change the variable name `column2` to whatever you named it)

```
column2.DataSource = sqlColumnSelectionList
```

It is important to remember that the `DataGridViewComboBox` works just like a normal `ComboBox` when it comes to initialisation and general usage.

Once you have that done, when adding rows you should change this line:

```
list_Destination_SQLMap.Rows.Add(sourceColumn, destcombo)
```

to be:

```
list_Destination_SQLMap.Rows.Add(sourceColumn, "")
```

This will add the new row to the DataGridView with an entry in the Text column matching the name of the field (as per your description) and the second column will be blank allowing the user to select the value from the drop down.

If you need the second column to be pre-selected to a value, replace the empty string with that value.

The DataGridViewComboBoxColumn only needs to be populated the once, and not every time a new cell is added to the DataGridView.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed!!