# Populate A DataGridViewComboBox

Tags: vb.net, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Looked at some of the suggested solutions couldn't find one that got me rolling.

I have a DataGrid that gets filled with the Following Code

```
        DataGridViewBranches.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridViewBranches.DataSource = FillBranchesDGV()

Private Function FillBranchesDGV()
Dim InstitutionsDT As New DataTable
    Dim cmdText As String

    cmdText = "SELECT examiners.last_name, examiners.examiner_ID, BranchInstitutions.* FROM BranchInstitutions INNER JOIN examiners ON BranchInstitutions.FldExaminer_ID = examiners.Examiner_ID where Company_Parent_ID=" & TextBoxCompanyParentID.Text

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(PubConnectionStrng)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            InstitutionsDT.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
  End Function
```

I have added a DgVComboBox and want to populate it with the Examiner Name. So that a user can change the examiners from the DGV.

[image]

I want to get rid on the 'Field Examiner' column and have the CBO there instead and have it changeable.

Being a ShadeTree VB coder, I am stumped.....

Any Help or push in the right direction appreciated.

A

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it should help point you in the direction you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202158/9365244.

Comment: Basically, you need to create a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` instead of a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and set the properties

Comment: Make a new query that includes the ID of the *examiner* and its name (whatever human-readable part you have). Set the `DisplayMember` of the DataGridViewComboBox to the name part, the `ValueMember` to the `examiners.examiner_ID` value and its `DataPropertyName` to the `FldExaminer_ID` field that you have to include. Hide this Column.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476)'s one I prepared earlier.